# How to use all the space for elements in GridLayout built dynamically

Tags: android, grid-layout

I need to create GridLayout dynamically and here's the result I'd like to get

[image]

I want to have this kind of layout with any text. But unfortunately for now, when text length of the child elements is different, layout looks different (spaces appear)

[image]

So, the question is: how to get the desired layout and avoid spaces?

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class GridLayoutTest extends Activity {

private static String arrayWithTheSameLength[] = {"tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", "tag5", "tag6", "tag7", "tag8", "tag9", "tag10"};
private static String arrayWithDifferentLength[] = {"adr", "asd", "asdfasdfasdf", "df", "asdfasdf", "asdfasdf", "fddfsf", "df", "sdfsdf", "dfgfgf"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(create(this));
}


public static View create(Context context) {
    GridLayout p = new GridLayout(context);
    p.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);

    GridLayout.Spec tag1colOdd = GridLayout.spec(0);
    GridLayout.Spec tag2colOdd = GridLayout.spec(1, 2, GridLayout.FILL);

    GridLayout.Spec tag1colEven = GridLayout.spec(0, 2, GridLayout.FILL);
    GridLayout.Spec tag2colEven = GridLayout.spec(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayWithDifferentLength.length; i++) {
        Button c = new Button(context);
        c.setText(arrayWithDifferentLength[i]);
        int row = i / 2;
        boolean firstColumn = i % 2 == 0;
        boolean evenRow = row % 2 == 0;
        if (evenRow) {
            p.addView(c, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row), firstColumn ? tag1colEven : tag2colEven));
        } else {
            p.addView(c, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row), firstColumn ? tag1colOdd : tag2colOdd));
        }

    }

    return p;
}
}
```

Comment: See the implementation of this library on github. I used it directly But you see the library copde and check if its on any use https://github.com/riontech-xten/StaggeredTextGridView

Comment: @MRX thanks for the hint, but I think it should't be that difficult to use extra library. I also think that solution in this library is overcomplicated..